# Declarative validation of forms in Java/Swing

Tags: java, validation, swing, declarative

I use Java for client-side development with Swing. I love Swing; I believe it is one of the better GUI frameworks there. What I miss, however, is the support for declarative validation. Like [this snippet](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Facet_Validation) from XForms.

Do you know any library which allows validating data entry in forms in a declarative way, not by writing ugly validation document listeners for every component there?

Comment: I wouldn't say client-side Swing is outdated.  It's probably what a significant portion of developers work on.

Comment: @mmyers: Is nice people still have manners. I think it's cultural, some places this is still strong. I would rever your edit except that... I can't anymore. :P

Comment: @Oscar: This has been discussed many times, and Jeff Atwood is in favor of removing salutations and signatures if you're already editing for some reason: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/#comment-15830.

Comment: @mmyers: I thought the removals were made by you, but now I see it was Rich B. I saw the thread  you mention when it was published,  but didn't feel like reading it. I think this is a subform of trolling. Anyway, it's the price to pay for the rules we have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try one of the implementations of [JSR 303 Bean Validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303). I don't think it is finalized yet but there are a few implementations around like
[Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/412.html) and [Agimatec Validation](http://code.google.com/p/agimatec-validation/). I haven't tried either but reading through some examples of how Bean Validation will be used makes it look promising. Here is an [interview](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-rest-us-%E2%80%93) with the spec lead. What I like most about the proposal is that the validation rules can be reused in different layers and with different frameworks. You can choose between annotations and xml for doing the 'declaring'.

Lastly you might want to check out [Swing Java Builders](http://code.google.com/p/javabuilders/) which provides a declarative way for defining GUIs and doing validation and data binding with Swing.

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting IE bugs or what, but the first link keeps running into the second link (so everything between "JSR 303" and "around like" is part of the link). With Joel Coehoorn's edits, the first link wasn't a link at all--it looked like "http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303>JSR 303"...

Comment: Maybe together with something like <a href="https://beansbinding.dev.java.net/">Beans Binding</a> or <a href="https://binding.dev.java.net/">JGoodies Binding</a>

Answer (score 1):

You may look at my attempt to build a Swing GUI builder, that uses JSR303 validation with Hibernate Validator: http://code.google.com/p/swing-formbuilder/

Answer (score 0):

You only have to write ugly validating models once. You can them use them in a "declarative way". Actual useful Swing libraries is a more difficult question.

Comment: I know. But I am facing a project with LOTS of forms (and validation rules), so I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What does the number of forms have to do with it?

Comment: It is reinventing the wheel. Why do you need to write email address validator? This things should be already implemented.